# Wrap numerical string in Lua

Tags: string, lua

Can somebody shed some lights on how to wrap string in `lua`? For instance, I have `123 234 345 456 567 788 890 098 678 854 531 489` and I want it to be wrapped in two lines:

```
 123 234 345 456 567 788 890 098  
 678 854 531 489
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to wrap an arbitrary string in a number of columns:

```
local char_pattern = ".[\128-\191]*"  -- for UTF-8 texts
-- local char_pattern = "."           -- for 1-byte encodings

local function wrap(text, width)
   local tail, lines = text.." ", {}
   while tail do
      lines[#lines + 1], tail = tail
         :gsub("^%s+", "")
         :gsub(char_pattern, "\0%0\0", width)
         :gsub("%z%z", "")
         :gsub("(%S)%z(%s)", "%1%2\0")
         :gsub("^(%z[^\r\n%z]*)%f[%s](%Z*)%z(.*)$", "%1\0%2%3")
         :match"^%z(%Z+)%z(.*)$"
   end
   return table.concat(lines, "\n")
end

-- Example:
print(wrap("123 234 345 456 567 788 890 098 678 854 531 489", 32))
-- Output:
-- 123 234 345 456 567 788 890 098
-- 678 854 531 489
```

Comment: Thanks @Egor Skriptunoff

Answer (score 3):

Lua has the same escape character as other programming languages: `\n`.

```
numbers = "123 234 345 456 567 788 890 098\n678 854 531 489"
>123 234 345 456 567 788 890 098
 678 854 531 489
```

Comment: I believe that does not answer the initial question at all. I'd read it as "how to wrap an arbitrary string in a number of columns".

Comment: Probably better to use multiline strings for that. E.g. numbers = [[123 234 345 456 567 788 890 098
678 854 531 489]] (with a newline in there that isn't rendered in this comment.)